# Python encode() doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, httprequest

I've tried `encode()` and it doesn't work. I keep getting `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` because normally I'd get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

```
ip = socket.gethostbyname("google.com")
port = 80
robot = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
payload = "Hello world"
try:
    robot.connect((ip, port)))
    robot.send('GET '+payload.encode()+' HTTP/1.1\n\n')
except socket.error:
    print("connection lost")
robot.close()
```

I dont understand what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`socket.send`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send), you can see that the first argument is `bytes`, not a string. You `encode` a string with a particular encoding to turn it into bytes, and you `decode` bytes with a particular encoding to turn them into a string:

```
robot.send(b'GET ' + payload.encode() + b' HTTP/1.1\n\n')
```

`str.encode` and `str.decode` default to `utf-8`.